# How to localize the mapbox geocoder for multiple languages?

Tags: javascript, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I create a mapbox map with a mapbox geocoder and want to get the same result even if the user is looking for a place in another language.

According to the [API documentation](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-geocoder/blob/master/API.md) it is possible to assign one or more language parameters as a string, separated by commas – but only the first one is used.

```
var geocoder = new MapboxGeocoder({
 accessToken: accessToken,
 mapboxgl: mapboxgl,
 language: 'en-US, de-DE'
});
```

When a user searches for `Munich`, I expect `Munich` in the result list and when he searches for `München`, I expect `München` or at least `Munich`.

Instead, when searching for `Munich` I actually get `Munich`, but when searching for `München` I only get hits in the vicinity (e.g. Marienplatz, Munich), but not the main hit.

Comment: This looks like a limitation in the Mapbox Geocoding API, https://docs.mapbox.com/api/search/#forward-geocoding. Although it returns both en_US and de_DE text for each result, it's favouring the first one for the search. I'm not sure how you can get it to favour both equally. I'd recommend reaching out to Mapbox Support.

Comment: Thanks @AndrewHarvey. I was surprised, because the documentation says that several values can be used. I'll check with the support.